# laravel file upload throws an error "file does not exist or is not readable."

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I'm trying to upload an image to `images` folder.

```
if ($request->hasFile('pic')) {
            $file = $request->file('pic');
            $file_name = time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $destinationPath = public_path('/images/');
            $file->move($destinationPath, $file_name);
            $model->pic= $file_name;
        }
```

But i get this error :

> The "./././php4E16.tmp" file does not exist or is not readable.

I'm uploading a photo for a post in other controller with same code and its working fine.

I can't figure out what's wrong .

I'm not trying to upload large size images or somthing.

although the php.ini is edited to accept large files .

what I have tried :

1. clearing the `cache`.
2. clearing the `config cache`.
3. updated Laravel version from `6.3` to `6.4`.
4. added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to form.

nothing works :\

I'm not sure whats happening here but the first time i tried to upload it worked but now its not working !

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to have these files in the public folder (ie, accessible to all), first do

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Then try something like this:

```
if ($filesFromRequest = $request->file('files')) {
      foreach ($files as $file) {
            $storedFilePath = $file->store('public/some_files');
            // Your Model Logic Here
        }         
}
```

If you need a full link to the file for the frontend, do:

```
echo asset('storage/some_files/file.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue was in the insert query ..

a column was not given a value.

I managed to see the error by installing laravel package `laravel-debugar`